# Nodejs limit language version switch

Tags: node.js

Having only one installation of nodejs (stable, 12) is it possible to tell node:

"Hey, I want to implement using features that are available in ECMAScript 2016 (ES7), if you see me using anything newer than that (say, `Promise.finally()` of ECMAScript 2018), issue an error"

Is there such a switch available for node, say

```
$ node --lang-spec-limit=ES2016 app.js
```

That is, without using a different version of node for for that purpose.

The purpose? Educational. Implement a project with ES5.1, then learn all features in ES2015, then move to next.